# How to properly log the "Path" in K8S ingress-nginx metrics

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, prometheus, nginx-ingress

I'm using [ingress-nginx](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx) as an Ingress controller for one of my services running over K8S (I'm using the nginx-0.20.0 release image with no specific metrics configurations in the K8S configmap the ingress-controller is using).

The nginx-ingress-controller pods are successfully scraped into my Prometheus server but all ingress metrics (e.g. `nginx_ingress_controller_request_duration_seconds_bucket`) show up with `path="/"` regardless of the real path of the handled request.

Worth noting that when I look at the ingress logs - the path is logged correctly.

How can I get the real path noted in the exported metrics?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you enabled vts metrics: `enable-vts-status: "true"`?

Comment: @mk_sta I tried it and it didn't seem to have any effect :( but thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Path` attribute in the NGINX metrics collected by prometheus derives from the Ingress definition yaml.

For example, if your ingress is:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
  name: <some-k8s-ingress-name>
  namespace: <some-k8s-namespace-name>
spec:
  rules:
  - host: <hostname>
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: <some-k8s-service-name>
          servicePort: <some-port>
        path: /
```

Then although NGINX will match any URL to your service, it'll all be logged under the path "`/`" (as seen [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/d74dea7585b7b26cf5a16ca9d7ac402b1e0cf8df/rootfs/etc/nginx/template/nginx.tmpl#L1010)).

If you want metrics for a specific URL, you'll need to explicitly specify it like this (notice the ordering of rules):

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
 annotations:
   kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
 name: <some-k8s-ingress-name>
 namespace: <some-k8s-namespace-name>
spec:
 rules:
 - host: <hostname>
   http:
     paths:
     - backend:
         serviceName: <some-k8s-service-name>
         servicePort: <some-port>
       path: /more/specific/path
     - backend:
         serviceName: <some-k8s-service-name>
         servicePort: <some-port>
       path: /
```

Comment: and thanks to [evgenyl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/398797/evgenyl) for leading me to understanding this!

Answer (score 1):

If I am understand right, this label was removed as causing high cardinality: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/2924#issuecomment-424516095

And this is more general issue: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/pull/2701

Have to say that I am pretty agree - think about it: if you allow the route to be the label value, it can be pretty easy to DDoS your Prometheus - just call your service with a lot of unexisting routes.

All those calls will be translated into the Label Values for all ingress metrics....

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I've gone through the threads and discovered the ingress controller behaves differently than I thought. In my ingress definition I used `path: /` to catch all calls to the service while thinking the controller would capture the exact path. But, it doesn't (not even with regex, from my trials). If I want the metrics to register for a specific path, I need to explicitly add a rule for that path. I'll post this as an answer.